# Updating Magento 2 using composer - zlib_decode(): data error

Tags: magento-2.1, upgrade, composer

I'm tried update my **Magento 2.1.0 to 2.1.5** using `composer update` and changing the `composer.json` file, but shows up this error message below, what can I do to run normally?

```
Failed to decode response: zlib_decode(): data error
```

Answer (score 6):

To me worked with the first solution, but you can try these:

**1 - Solution**

Run the composer update with this param.

```
composer clear-cache && composer update -vvv
```

It will equilibrate the requests and fix the **time out** that caused this issue.

**2- Solution (only Linux)**

On linux, it seems that running this command helps to make ipv4 traffic have a higher prio than ipv6, which is a better alternative than disabling ipv6 entirely:

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'precedence ::ffff:0:0/96 100' >> /etc/gai.conf"
```

[Official documentation about](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#degraded-mode)

Comment: first solution works